# Estimate Number Of Decimal Places of Time Series

Tags: python, numpy

How do I estimate the number of decimal places for the numbers used inside a pandas time series?

e.g.  for

```
x=[1.01,1.01,1.03]
```

i would want

```
in[0]: estimate_decimal_places(x)
out[0] : 2
```

e.g.  for

```
x=[1.1,1.5,2.0]
```

i would want

```
in[0]: estimate_decimal_places(x)
out[0] : 1
```

Comment: If you had a function to return the number of decimal places in a single float, you could do `max(estimate_decimal_places(f) for f in x)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def estimate_decimal_places(num):
return len(str(num).split(".")[1])    

x=[1.1,1.01,1.001]

for num in x:
    print estimate_decimal_places(num)
```

gives

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: Fails for `1.0` and `1.000000000001`. Otherwise it's sweet and simple.

Comment: 1.0 has 1 decimal place, so think it does not fail here. But the problem with 1.000000000001 seems to be the machine precision, it's rounded to 1

Comment: The machine precision is good to at least 15 digits, so it's a built-in cutoff in `str` that's the problem. And I would argue that `1.0` actually has 0 places, it's equivalent to `float(1)`.

Comment: from a scientific point of view (i'm a physicist) 1.0 is different from 1 because the ".0" indicates a certain precision... but anyway...

Comment: You're correct of course, except that Python doesn't give you a way to represent zero places in a floating-point number. You can get it with the Decimal module though.

Answer (score 1):

Really ugly, but it works, and should cover the corner cases pointed out by Mark

```
def decimal_places(num):
    return max(len(('%.15f'%num).strip("0").split('.')[1]),0)
```

EDIT:

this fails anyway with something like `decimal_places(90.34)`. On my machine when printed it gets converted to 90.340000000000003, and then this in turn gives the wrong result.

It works decently as long as you don't push it too much, accepting to be unable to predict decimal places above `12` digits for example, replacing `15` with `12` above

Comment: Unfortunately any fixed number of places you choose to format will be wrong outside of a small range of values. You really need something more adaptive.